# How to insert a object in an array (as a element )

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am from C++ background.
I am trying to translate a C++ code to JavaScript.

in C++ we have vector < pair < int,int > > to store pairs.

in JS i have a situation. i want to store 2D coordinates. i actually want to push new coordinates to the array.

i did like

1. first I created a Object

```
const coordinate = {
   x= 9,
   y= 10
}
```

2. Then i tried to push that object into the array `CoordinateStorage` that i want this object to get stored

```
CoordinatesStorage.unshift({X : coordinate.x, Y : coordinates.y});
```

I know this code shown above is absolutely wrong to store an object into the array. I searched out for sources but i got nothing useful.
Please recommend some sources that i can refer for such translation related problems if possible.

Comment: _Please recommend some sources that i can refer for such translation related problems_ there's no such resource which teaches how to translate C++ code into javascript. You just have to learn the javascript language. [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) are a good place to start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, we should use the `.push` method for an array.
There are other methods available you can find them here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array but the `.push` method for your case is more suitable.

Basically, as a result, we want to have something like this:
`[ {x: 2, y: 4 }, { x: 2, y: 4 } ]` We have an array of objects.

Or we could also have an array of arrays:
`[[1, 2], [3, 4], [4, 6]]` Not sure if it okay for your case, but maybe as an option.

Also, we could create a class `Vector` and we might have something like
`[ Vector { x: 1, y: 2 }, Vector { x: 3, y: 4 }, Vector { x: 4, y: 6 } ]`

Let's take a look at the examples:

1. Using the plain object for the vector:

```
    const coordinate1 = {
      x: 2,
      y: 4
    };
    const coordinate2 = {
      x: 3,
      y: 4
    };

    const coordinatesStorage = [];
    coordinatesStorage.push(coordinate1);
    coordinatesStorage.push(coordinate2);
```

If you will do `console.log(coordinatesStorage)` you will see `[ { x: 2, y: 4 }, { x: 3, y: 4 } ]`

2. Using the array to store a vector:

```
    const coordinate1 = [1, 2];
    const coordinate2 = [3, 4];
    const coordinatesStorage = [];
    coordinatesStorage.push(coordinate1);
    coordinatesStorage.push(coordinate2);
```

The coordinatesStorage will be `[ [ 1, 2 ], [ 3, 4 ] ]`

3. Using the Vector class:

Maybe in your case, it would be more helpful to operate with a class Vector:

```
class Vector {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
}

const coordinatesStorage = [];

coordinatesStorage.push(new Vector(1, 2));
coordinatesStorage.push(new Vector(3, 4));
coordinatesStorage.push(new Vector(4, 6));
```

And here in the console you will see `[ Vector { x: 1, y: 2 }, Vector { x: 3, y: 4}, Vector { x: 4, y: 6 } ]`

Take a look at the Vector implementations in JS:

1. https://gist.github.com/jjgrainger/808640fcb5764cf92c3cad960682c677
2. https://github.com/maxkueng/victor/blob/master/index.js

I hope this helps. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

First initialize the array

```
var CoordinatesStorage = [];

//create object
const coordinate = {
   x: 9,  // Note - the operator is colon : not = as in the question
   y: 10
}

// push to array
CoordinatesStorage.push(coordinate);
```

Now your array will be like this `[{x:9, y:10}]` if you push again the array will be `[{x:9, y:10}, {x:9, y:10}]`

**Tip:** Arrays are denoted by square brackets eg:  `['math', 'science', 'english']`

Objects are denoted by key-value pairs wrapped in curly  brackets

```
eg:  var student = {
                      name: "John", // string value
                      age: 6, // integer value
                      sex: "M",
                      phone: [123456789 , 564654654] // value is of array of 2 items
                   }
```